# File not fully converting form text to csv

Tags: python-2.7

I can convert a text file to csv with no problems. However, when I attempt the convert a csv back to text. I am only getting the first line (header), all other data is not written. Below is the code that I'm using. Any direction is appreciated. I'm dragging and dropping the files on the script:

```
import os, sys
import csv


# Make sure a folder or directory was specified
if len(sys.argv) == 1:
   sys.exit(1)


# Assign name of file or folder to variable
resource = sys.argv[1]


#create CSV filename as TEXT
textFile = os.path.splitext(resource)[0] + '.txt'


with open(resource, 'rb') as fin:
     with open(textFile, 'wb') as fout:
         reader = csv.DictReader(fin)
         writer = csv.DictWriter(fout, reader.fieldnames, delimiter='|')
         writer.writeheader()
         writer.writerows(reader)
```

Comment: Have you opened your csv file in a text editor to make sure it has data?

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Yes, the file definitely has data.

Comment: Perhaps it's time for some old-fashioned print-statement debugging.  Before creating your reader object do `print fin.readlines();fin.seek(0)`.  Replace `writer.writerows(reader)` with `for row in reader:print row;writer.writerow(row)`.